# R, Bonferonni and Holm Tests

Tags: r, statistics, bonferroni

Comparing Bonferonni & holm

> pairwise.t.test(y,grp,p.adj = "bonferroni")

```
Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD
```

data:  y and grp

```
     Nitro A Nitro B None    Pharma A
```

Nitro B  1.00000 -       -       -
None     0.00062 0.00032 -       -
Pharma A 1.00000 1.00000 7.1e-07 -
Pharma B 0.14510 0.62309 4.4e-08 1.00000

P value adjustment method: bonferroni

> pairwise.t.test(y,grp,p.adj = "holm")

```
Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD
```

data:  y and grp

```
     Nitro A Nitro B None    Pharma A
```

Nitro B  0.86554 -       -       -
None     0.00043 0.00025 -       -
Pharma A 0.46289 0.86554 6.4e-07 -
Pharma B 0.08706 0.31155 4.4e-08 0.86554

P value adjustment method: holm

I need to comment on the differences between holm and bonferonni and not quite sure what to say about the differences between the tests and why i would use one not the other, any help or advice appreciated, didnt edit so would be appreciated as well

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please state as much.

Comment: no, it is not, it is a question as part of revision, a similar question may come up in an exam so it is hard to find out the answer via lecture notes etc.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming issue but a statistics question. Short answer: Bonferroni corrects all significance thresholds by the same value (the number of tests), while Holm's method modifies the threshold sequentially from lowest (raw) p-value to highest

Comment: did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method?